# How to get something like sql '%test%words%' in linq

Tags: linq

I know how to use .Contains for looking up '%testwords%', my question is about how to use linq to get '%test%words%'. Thanks

Comment: To clarify: Are you trying to find records which have "test" plus records which have "words" or is it inclusive in that all records must have the word "test" and "words"?

Comment: @Chris, I want to the exact function like sql statement "like '%test%word%'", and we are not allowed to use linq to sql

Comment: I saw that and fixed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like this if you're not using Linq to SQL:

```
var query = from o in yourObject
            where  o.field.Contains("test")
            where o.field.Contains("words")
            where o.field.indexOf("test") < o.field.indexOf("words")
            select o;
```

if you are using Linq to SQL, use the SqlMethods that Stefanvds showed.

Answer (score 1):

```
.Where(q => SqlMethods.Like(q,"%test%words%"))
```

use SqlMethods

Comment: how about the % in the middle?

Comment: Thanks, Stefanvds. We are not allowed to use linq to sql

Comment: it is not meaning that it is not correct answer. You cna change Linq To Sql syntax to LINQ. It s not difficult. "Your code is correct Stefandvds"

Answer (score 0):

well, i think the answer is NO :(

Probably the closest answer is lst.Where(foo.Contains("test") && foo.Contains("word")), though that statement doesnt give the right sequence as '%test%word%'